# How to SELECT infinity deep loop data with SELF JOIN

Tags: sql, self-join

Trying to project effective DataBase: 
We look at advertisements, where sellers post their phone numbers, sellers can have more than one phone number, and sellers can post their phones in different ways... 
simple image to clearly understand:
[image]
I want to find ALL advertisements, phoneS and target seller knowing just one phone [phone_1|phone_2|...|phone_4]!

Here is the table structure I want to use: 
[image]

Where you can notice:

1. Advertisement_1010001 has THREE phones: ..0001, ..0002, ..0003.
2. Advertisement_1010003 has TWO phones:  ..0003, ..0004.
3. Advertisement_1010004 has ONE phone: ..0004.
4. (all advs. foregoing were published with ONE seller, because ALL phones LINKED!)
5. Advertisement_1010005 has TWO phones, but it belongs it belongs to another seller.

All is good, but how can I "SELECT phone, adver_num WHERE my_phone IN (head & tail_phones)" using just ONE query?

I am sure, self join will help me, but the way I am using it now is not very appropriate:

```
SELECT  a1.`advert_site_num`,
        a1.`head_phone`
FROM `test_table` a1
LEFT JOIN `test_table` a2 ON a1.`tail_phones` = a2.`head_phone` 
UNION
SELECT  a3.`advert_site_num`,
        a3.`tail_phones`
FROM `test_table` a3
LEFT JOIN `test_table` a4 ON a3.`tail_phones` = a4.`head_phone`
ORDER BY `advert_site_num`, `head_phone`;
```

returns all records linked by phone whithout filtering with searching phone

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just filter with where? I'm not sure to understand your problem:

```
SELECT `advert_site_num`, GROUP_CONCAT(`phone` SEPARATOR ',') FROM (
    SELECT  `advert_site_num`,
            `tail_phones` AS `phone`
    FROM `test_table`
    WHERE a1.`tail_phones` = myphone
    UNION
    SELECT  `advert_site_num`,
            `head_phone` AS `phone`
    FROM `test_table`
    WHERE a1.`head_phone` = myphone
)
GROUP BY `advert_site_num`;
```

Comment: No, it does not solve the problem. 
It only returns a string in which a specified number is found, 
and not the entire chain of phones.